# How to disable serializable state invariant middleware

Tags: redux, rtk-query

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [userAuthApi.reducerPath]: userAuthApi.reducer,
    cart:cartSlice.reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(userAuthApi.middleware)
})
```

The Above is My store configuration

I am getting error saying serializable state invariant middleware took too long if your state or actions very large disable the middleware, i don't have a large state at all, Actions means which actions it's talking about , i am getting this error a after adding one more api to my end points of rtk query , how many endpoints are too many.

My development Mode is slowed down to very very low , causing me so much problem while building what's causing this , what's the solution

Comment: How big are the state values and API responses that you're dealing with? The serializability middleware shouldn't be slow unless you're dealing with a gigantic state.

Comment: i am displaying categories from a api response like 70 something categories is that causing this??

Comment: Do size of data from api response affect the speed of application?